# How to format Cookie in POST method to match iOS

Tags: android, ios, cookies, httpurlconnection

Trying to replicate this iOS code over to my Android httpUrlConnection post method, below is the objc:

```
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                             NSHTTPCookiePath: @"/",
                             NSHTTPCookieDomain: [request.URL host],
                             NSHTTPCookieName: @"session_state",
                             NSHTTPCookieValue: state,
                             };

NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];
NSDictionary *cookieHeaders = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:@[cookie]];
```

And here is what I have setup in my Android app:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "session_state=" + state);
```

My question is how do I properly match these two so that my Android cookie is equivalent to the iOS example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question I gwent with an httpClient and httpPost instead of httpUrlConnection which looks something like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", "session_state=" + state);
```